# Commit count in Cake build script?

Tags: c#, git, cakebuild

We’re migrating to using Cake build scripts for our CI pipeline and in our build process we identify builds with the commit count using the output from command `git rev-list --all –count`.

Is there a native way for this in Cake without shelling out to the git command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there’s no built-in alias for this, there’s an addin to Cake called [Cake.Git](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Git) which enables you to achieve what you’re asking for.

Example usage:

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Git

DirectoryPath repoPath = Directory("path to repo");

var commits = GitLog(repoPath, int.MaxValue);

Information("Number of commits: {0}", commits.Count);
```

Will out put something like

```
Number of commits: 1539
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to point out an alternative as well...

I, and Cake itself, use a tool called [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) to assert a semantic version number, based on the git commit history.  Just wanted to point it out, in case it might be a good fit for your pipeline.